# UFW white list ip address and domaines?

Tags: linux, ufw

is it possible to have some sort of white list of IPs addresses and domains name allowed for incoming traffic and block all the rest? or is it better to enable incoming traffic whenever I want to download something and disable it after?

please advise what's the best approach for both incoming and outgoing traffic.